# hg serve in MacHg

Tags: mercurial, machg

I tried to find it in documentation, but couldn't, how can I run Mercurial server (as hg serve in terminal) from MacHg, is it possible at all? I'm on Mac 10.6 if it's important.

thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be on SuperUser?

Comment: I've seen many questions about Mercurial here

Comment: I think this question belongs here: http://groups.google.com/group/machg_mercurial

I think it is better for users and developers if the questions about a given piece of software can be concentrated in a single place, hopefully the projects own mailinglist.

Answer (score 2):

As per MacHG documentation:

> You can use the command line version of Mercurial (via the Terminal)
>   interchangeably with MacHg. You can freely download and install
>   whichever version of Mercurial you want on your machine and it will
>   not conflict with MacHg since an independent copy of Mercurial is
>   bundled inside the MacHg application. (In fact MacHg does this to
>   ensure there are no conflicts or other problems with the users
>   Mercurial configuration.)

You can use regular mercurial binary from standard installation to serve repository

> hg serve

And continue to use machg independently of that. Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: @Burjua: My answer is bit late but hope you have already arrived at this conclusion.